# Why does changing the numpy.array dtype from int to float change the output of numpy.imshow()

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, python-imaging-library, dtype

Today, I came across a weird thing that I cannot explain and cannot find an answer to. 
Maybe I have some fundamental misunderstanding and I am not seeing the obvious, but I guess I am at the point where I will bite the bullet of being called out over now knowing what is going on.

I am loading some image data using PIL and converting it into a numpy array. Nothing fancy here. 
However, I am then changing the data type from integer to float so I can normalize the RGB channels in a later step.

I would expect that changing the datatype from int to float wouldn't really change the image in any way. However ...

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open("test.jpg")
```

before the dtype change:

```
plt.imshow(np.array(im))
```

[image]

after the dtype change:

```
plt.imshow(np.array(im).astype(float))
```

[image]

Is this what one would expect? If so ... why? What am I missing?

Cheers & thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check the docs you'll see that `imshow` expects:

> - (M, N): an image with scalar data. The values are mapped to colors using normalization and a colormap. See parameters norm, cmap, vmin, vmax.
> - (M, N, 3): an image with RGB values (**0-1 float** or 0-255 int).

So when the are of dtype `float`, it expects them to be in the range `0-1`, hence we have to divide it by 255 to get the expected result, otherwise you will see the *negative* of the image.

Here's an example using a sample image from `sklearn.datasets`:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_sample_images
dataset = load_sample_images()     
first_img_data = dataset.images[0]
plt.imshow(first_img_data)
```

[image]

In order to limit the values in the range `0`-`1`, we just have to divide by `255`:

```
plt.imshow(first_img_data.astype(float)/255)
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you see the negative of the image?

Comment: Thanks. It makes sense when you explain it like that.

Comment: Well @mad ... The question from the link asks exactly that. That is how i saw myself which is the reason by seing that post. I figured just directing you to it is the easiest way

Comment: I wasn't being sarcastic, but looking back I can see that there's no other way to read my comment. The effect of re-multiplying by 255 is indeed clearly the issue.

Comment: Thank you! Duh, in retrospect.

Answer (score 0):

The following is written in the `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow` function:

```
Parameters:
        X : array-like or PIL image
            The image data. Supported array shapes are:
            - (M, N): an image with scalar data. The values are mapped to
              colors using normalization and a colormap. See parameters *norm*,
              *cmap*, *vmin*, *vmax*.
            - (M, N, 3): an image with RGB values (0-1 float or 0-255 int).
            - (M, N, 4): an image with RGBA values (0-1 float or 0-255 int),
              i.e. including transparency.
```

this work for you:

> `plt.imshow(np.array(im).astype(float)/255)`